# Can 2 sequential diffs be patched to output a 3rd diff that reflects all the changes combined from former 2 diffs?

Tags: version-control, diff

Given `diff(a,b)` & `diff(b,c)`
Is there a way to find `diff(a,c)` without knowledge of a or b or c ?

Note : I'm using diff utility in GNU.

Is there any existing solution for this ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Theoretically it is the superposition of the two diffs, but practically it's probably much more complicated because you need to **parse** the files `diff(a,b)` and `diff(b,c)`.

Comment: Yes, I believe its theoretically possible. I am interested in finding out any existing solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `combinediff` utility from the [patchutils](http://freshmeat.net/projects/patchutils/) package does exactly this.

Comment: damn. beat me to it. also take a look at interdiff

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
git checkout HEAD@{0}           # leave the branch
git reset HEAD~3                # unstage last 3 commits
git diff > ~/mypatch
```

perhaps start and end with

```
git stash
# do funny business
git checkout $originalbranch
git stash pop
```